# ошибка скрипта активного пункта меню в мою версии

Tags: javascript, jquery

как устранить ошибку на мобильном.
если в мобильной версии убрать `$("ul li a.active").parents("ul").show();` то сайт работает, если этот кусок кода оставить то в моб версии не работает. Может как проверку сделать, если класс active у ul li a ?
вот скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vmenu = $('#menu > li.sub > .icon-angle-down');
  vmenu.on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#menu li ul').slideUp();
   if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
       $(this).next().slideUp();
   } else {
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   }
  });

    $("ul li a.active").parents("ul").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $(".vertical-menu ul li a").hasClass("active") ) {

$(".vertical-menu ul li a.active").parents("ul").show();
}
```

так вроде работает